# Tableau, create 2 action filter in one click

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 sheets in my dasshboard: Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3.

**sheet1** have 3 dimensions on row: Id, ModelId, Date.

**sheet2** have 2 Dimension on row: Id, ModelId.

**sheet3** have 2 Dimension on row:Id, Date.

I want to create 2 filter actions that run on select cell in **sheet1** and send to **sheet2** Id, ModelId and to **sheet3** Id and Date.
Is it possible?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a dashboard put all 3 reports on that dashboard.

Go in dashboard->action in that create an action on select,

In the source keep sheet1 and in target keep sheet2 and sheet3.

It should work.